# Lock a folder which can be unlocked only by the application - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to help myself with an addiction I have with a game, so I created a program in Java which locks a folder and unlocks it after 1,2 or 3 hour. The problem is that I can't trick myself. I use the commands:

```
File f1 = new File(Your file path);
f1.setExecutable(false);
f1.setWritable(false);
f1.setReadable(false);
```

to lock the game folder (and not be able to play the game) but I can easily right click it and change the permissions. Is there a way that I can change folder permissions only from inside the Java application?

You can view my code [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:50b4). Mind that you have to install [JFolderChooser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfolderchooser/).

Comment: Delete the file? I'm sure that would help. If all else fails, format your hard drive, and put it in a microwave

Comment: Deleting system32 usually helps. :)

Comment: Or.... You could write an application to delete that game... Then after a couple hours or so, go re-download the game and run through the installer ;)

Comment: Generate a random String an encrypt that folder. Later that application can decrypt it with the same key.  ... and don't close the application before it could decrypt the folder ;).

Comment: Or even better, why not just zip it up with a random password that is only available to you after a certain time limit?

Comment: Yes that's a good approach, thanks

Comment: you could make your program play a very loud awful sound. That would put you away from opening the game.

Comment: Jihed Amine, I am not a dog :)